# using a struct from a different file in a header

Tags: c, struct, include

I have defined a struct (let call it test) in file a.h, this struct should be used by many files.
In the file b.h I need to use this struct, but not as a pointer (`struct test a[32]` and not `struct test* a`) as one of the attributes of another struct (let call it test_container).
but I'm receiving `error: array type has incomplete element type`.
I'm guessing it happening because the compiler does not know the test struct, so it can't determent how much space does test_container required.
so I'm trying to add `#include <a.h>` in b.h, but then I'm receiving  `fatal error: a.h: No such file or directory`. both files are in the same directory.
what is the problem?

Comment: post code rather than a description of code.  It's much easier to read, and more accurate.  That said, you should probably `#include "a.h"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `#include "a.h"` to include your own `.h`.

By the way you should post real code instead of description.